# Reading input with fgets?

Tags: c, fgets

I am trying to get the input of one character using fgets(). To my knowledge fgets will addend the \n to the end of the input unless there is no room.

```
char test[1];
fgets(test,1,stdin);
readRestOfLine();
while (strcmp(test,"z") != 0){
......
......
}
```

Anyway the loop is never run even when z is entered. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

`man fgets`

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`
>
> **fgets()** reads in at most one less than *size* characters from *stream* and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by *s*...
>   A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

In your case of *size* 1 this means **fgets()** reads in zero, i. e. no, characters and stores the terminating '\0' in `test[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` operates on strings as follows from it's name, so `test` has to be `\0` terminated string. `test` must have room for `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated correctly `fgets` appends a '\n' at the end of the string. So if you input just "z", then the resulting string will be "z\n" which is not equal to "z".

Furthermore the size of the buffer for `fgets` is only on character long in your program, but this length must be at least as long as your longest string you intend to enter.

Try this:

```
char test[100];   // space for 98 characters + \n + terminating zéro
fgets(test, 100, stdin);
readRestOfLine();
while (strcmp(test,"z\n") != 0){
   ......
   ......
}
```